# Integration of Syncfusion Organizational Chart Control into MAUI Application

Tags: blazor, maui, syncfusion

I want to implement a hierarchical organizational chart in MAUI application.
Syncfusion provides a javascript-ui-control called organizational-chart(link below) and blazor component for the organizational-chart(link below) which pefectly suits my requirement.

https://www.syncfusion.com/javascript-ui-controls/js-diagram/javascript-library-organizational-chart

https://www.syncfusion.com/blazor-components/blazor-diagram/blazor-library-organizational-chart

Is there any way to use this control in a MAUI application?

If not possible then Is there any MAUI control which syncfusion offers to draw the organizational-chart

based on hierarchical data (sunburst doesn't fit our requirement )?

Comment: You should just go to the Syncfusion website and browse through all of the controls they currently have available for Maui. Not just the demo page as that does not list them all. Go to the documentation there is a full list of available controls. This is not a question for Stack Overflow.